# Unable to import cv2

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I tested the following command in python:

```
import cv2
```

I put it in the file `b.py` and run `python b.py`. But I met with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/mypath/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libXdmcp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What's wrong with this? Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: Can you please post the content of `b.py`? I created one with `import cv2` and `from .cv2 import *` in it and got an `ImportError: No module named cv2` but not your error. It looks like anaconda is trying to import something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install opencv correctly? Also what OS are you using (e.g. Windows, Linux OS X etc.)

If you're using windows - did you follow these steps?:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/de5/tutorial_py_setup_in_windows.html

If you are using Fedora install Opencv by typing this command into the terminal:

```
sudo yum install numpy opencv*
```

The cause of the problem may be that you haven't installed the dependencies:

- Matplotlib
- Numpy

Hope this helps!

Comment: To me it's clear from the file path and the shared object type that the OP is using Linux. I might be mistaken, of course.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Anyways to get root permision type sudo at the beginning of the command. (I have edited my answer)